# Full Process cube in SSIS

Tags: ssis, olap-cube, xmla

I have a XMLA script like below to process (full process) the cube

```
<Object>
    <DatabaseID>Adventure Works DW Standard Edition</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>Adventure Works DW</CubeID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
```

Will this full process the dimension or do I need to write another script for dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will only process your cube, not the dimensions related to it.

A possible solution could be to process the entire database (assuming it only contains one cube). This way all objects in it will be processed.

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>Adventure Works DW Standard Edition</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```